# How to stop Slide effect if the Div is already selected or opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a Single Paee website using `toggle()` method of jquery. I have 4 Headings `Parent1` 'Parent2' & `Parent3`. All  have child Divs.

I want to show the `Child1` div only, and hide all other Divs, if `parent1` is selected or clicked. I have written the following code, its not working fine but when i click on `parent` div second time its hides the element, and if i click it again it shows the element.

Kindly tell me how to resolve this problem.

```
<body>
<div class="parents">
    <div id="parent1"> <h1>First</h1></div>
    <div id="parent2"> <h1>Second</h1></div>
    <div id="parent3"> <h1>Third</h1></div>
</div>


<br />
<br />

<div class="childs">

    <div id="child1"> <h3>First</h3></div>
    <div id="child2"> <h3>Second</h3></div>
    <div id="child3"> <h3>Third</h3></div>
</div>   

</body>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("#child2").hide();
    $("#child3").hide();    


    $("#parent1").click(function(){

        $("#child2").hide();
        $("#child3").hide();
        $("#child1").toggle('left');
        return false;

        }); 


if ($("#child2").hide())
{

    $("#parent2").click(function(){

        $("#child1").hide();
        $("#child3").hide();
        $("#child2").toggle('left');
        return false;

        }); 
}


    $("#parent3").click(function(){

        $("#child2").hide();
        $("#child1").hide();
        $("#child3").toggle('left');
        return false;

        }); 

});
```

Comment: Instead of toggle use .show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do nothing, if you click again on a opened spot.

Try,

```
var child = $('.childs >div').hide();

$('.parents > div').click(function () {
    var targetDiv = child.eq($(this).index());
    if (targetDiv.is(':visible')) { return false; }
    targetDiv.siblings().hide().end().toggle('left');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vjMzz/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML attribute `data-target=""`

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/D94DN/2/)**</kbd>

html

```
<div class="parents">
    <div id="parent1" data-target="#child1">
         <h1>First</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="parent2" data-target="#child2">
         <h1>Second</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="parent3" data-target="#child3">
         <h1>Third</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="childs">
    <div id="child1">
         <h3>First</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
         <h3>Second</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="child3">
         <h3>Third</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.childs div').addClass('hidden');
    function changeDiv() {
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $('.childs div').addClass('hidden');
        $(target).removeClass('hidden');
    }
    $('.parents div').click(changeDiv);
});
```

**EDIT** : jquery edited to make all `.childs div` hidden initially

Comment: Don't make the things complex..!

Comment: How does it becomes complex using `data-target` ? people are posting various ways I included one of other way.

Comment: Hey cool, i actually removed that, because of the effort that you made towards this.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
  $('.parents div').click(function(){
   $('.childs div').not(':eq('+$(this).index()+')').hide();
   $('#child'+($(this).index()+1)).toggle();
  });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UtALA/)**

if you dont want to toogle and simply show then:

```
  $('.parents div').click(function(){
   $('.childs div').not(':eq('+$(this).index()+')').hide();
   $('#child'+($(this).index()+1)).show();
  });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SMBxb/)**

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D39Yx/4/)**

try this . get selected element `index` based on that you can toggle the element

```
 $(".parents").click(function (e) {

        $(".childs").children().hide().eq($("H1").index(this)).toggle("left");

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your code like this and do a if condition to check if ele is hidden:

```
$('.parents div').click(function () {
    var idx = $(this).index() + 1;
    if(!$('#child' + idx).is(':visible')) 
      $('#child' + idx).hide().slideDown().siblings().hide();
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p66zk/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.toggle()` use `.show()` method, it will be always static.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3NkCd/)